# Linear or Nonlinear Regression of Multiple matrices with R?

Tags: r, matrix, model, regression, sparse-matrix

I have many matrices of quantitative variables, let me start with three matrices of proportions. To variabilities between samples, I would like to detect variables correlation between "contents from M1", "Variables from M2" and "Chemical from M3" by comparing these matrices. The problem is that i have only 6 samples, I tried sparse compositional model with a R package, it does not work because I have a small sample number n <10.

Could you please help me for the model choice and adequate R PACKAGES? 
Should I start with iterative process by trying a small number of variable from each matrice?

example of my three matrices :

Matrice 1

```
    Content1 Content2   Content3 Content4 .... Content150
Sample1
Sample2
Sample3
Sample4
Sample5
Sample6
```

Matrice 2

```
    V1  V2  V3  V4 ... V20
Sample1
Sample2
Sample3
Sample4
Sample5
Sample6
```

Matrice 3

```
    Chemical1   Chemical1   Chemical1 .... chemical30
Sample1
Sample2
Sample3
Sample4
Sample5
Sample6
```

Comment: With only 6 samples, you'll hardly get any significant results. If taking more samples is not an option, maybe using bootstrapping may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I agree with your critics, but in my case each sample is very expensive experimentally to do it. I do not know which  regression model could allow the sampling with replacement as are you suggesting.

Comment: I might ask you to read some tips on how to ask a question here. One of them is [link](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2014/10/missing-stackoverflow-topic-terrible-question/). Also the answer to the question on [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) is useful.

Comment: Instead of being critical on formalities of "How to ask question" or "How to reply to a comment" I am only attending scientific suggestions. Reminding me the formality rules is nice but still poor of sense regarding my scientific question.

Comment: @user3064106 It depends on what you are trying to explain with your model. Do you want a independent model (such as cluster analysis) or a dependent model (such as linear multiple regression)? In the second case, what is your dependent variable like? Continuous, discrete, binary?

Comment: I want to do both independent and dependent model, since I have a continuous compositional data in first (i.e in M1 "relative abundance" expressed as proportions of microorganisms in water sample). I would explain variables relationship's(Pearson correlation) within one matrice and between matrices. I want to start with multiple regression, but I do not know which fit better my data, linear or nonlinear regression models? for this moment I am trying to see which distribution I have to decide linearity from curvilinearity from nonlinearity

Comment: I forget to mention that I have transformed my original matrices to dissimilarity distances between samples